# Is there a quick way of producing comparative benchmark graphs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, benchmarking, performance-testing

I want perform comparative benchmarks between two matrix multiplications implementations in Ruby: the first one with the standard library Matrix class and the other using the [nmatrix-atlas](https://rubygems.org/gems/nmatrix-atlas) gem (that is a Ruby wrapper over ATLAS).

The benchmarking should be performed over a series of inputs and should show a line graph that has the input size on the X axis and time taken on the Y axis.

The code that I'm using currently looks like this:

```
require 'nmatrix'
require 'nmatrix/atlas'
require 'matrix'
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  [5, 50, 500].each do |size|
    x.report("nm-atlas with size #{size}") do
      n = NMatrix.new([size,size], [1]*size*size, dtype: :float32)
      n.dot(n)
    end
  end

  [5, 50, 500].each do |size|
    x.report("ruby matrix with size #{size}") do
      n = Matrix[*[[1]*size]*size]
      n * n
    end
  end
end
```

The output that this produces is rather not very friendly to the eyes (and quickly becomes so once the number of inputs and test cases increases). Here's how it looks:

```
   user     system      total        real
nm-atlas with size 5  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000194)
nm-atlas with size 50  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.000724)
nm-atlas with size 500  0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.084939)
ruby matrix with size 5  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000207)
ruby matrix with size 50  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.055106)
ruby matrix with size 500 51.040000   0.000000  51.040000 ( 51.068719)
```

Displaying only the 'real' values would also be fine. Any ideas on a better solution for comparing benchmarks?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a solution to this so I just went ahead and came up with one on my own in the form of the [benchmark-plot](https://rubygems.org/gems/benchmark-plot) gem.

It basically accepts any object that is Enumerable, iterates over the objects inside it and plots the results on a graph using [gruff](https://github.com/topfunky/gruff). To benchmark matrix multiplication with [NMatrix](https://github.com/sciruby/nmatrix) vs Ruby Matrix, the following code can be used:

```
require 'benchmark/plot'
require 'matrix'
require 'nmatrix'
require 'nmatrix/atlas'

sizes = [5, 10, 50, 100, 150, 200]

Benchmark.plot sizes, title: "Matrix multiplication",
  file_name: "matrix_multiplication" do |x|
  x.report "NMatrix with ATLAS" do |size|
    n = NMatrix.new([size,size], [1]*size*size, dtype: :float32)
    n.dot(n)
  end

  x.report "Matrix" do |size|
    n = Matrix[*[[1]*size]*size]
    n * n
  end
end
```

This will create the following graph:
[image: NMatrix vs Ruby Matrix multiplication]